# Twitter to Facebook connection is not working

Tags: facebook, twitter

I'm trying to connect a Twitter account to a Facebook one.

I have connected the Facebook account from [App Settings](https://twitter.com/settings/applications) in Twitter and Authorized Twitter Application.

However, Tweets are not being posted to the Facebook account, and every time I visit the App Settings page in Twitter, I find that the Facebook account is disconnected.

I tried to disconnect both Facebook and Twitter, clear cache, restart browser and try reconnecting again (as mentioned in [Twitter Help Center](https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170742-facebook)), but it is still not working.

Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: same problem here... I also tried to follow [this guide](https://sgoodger.wordpress.com/2011/02/11/twitter-to-facebook/), but when I visit https://apps.facebook.com/twitter/ it shows an error: "Sorry, the application you were using is misconfigured. Please try again later."

Comment: In [this guide](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/forwarding-tweets-facebook-33232.html) they say that the tweet must be composed including the #fb tag, but it not worked for me...

Comment: @neoDev The problem is that I have another old Twitter account connected to Facebook and it is working perfect, it could be a new bug after a certain update for Twitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all, the problem was with cookies, deleting all the cookies (in addition to the cache) and restarting the browser solved the problem!